# How to invoke the action "Cancel Request" from the Requests page?

Tags: acumatica

I've tried looking for the action definition in the page's graph without any results. There are no public PXActions associated to that button.

When the graph is instantiated, Visual Studio's intellisense does not show any references to that action or to a linked method.
This is occurring in different Acumatica versions.

There are also no references to the inclusion of this button in the Actions dropdown with the AddMenuAction() method

I find it odd that this particular action would be hidden.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some actions in Acumatica may exist only in the "Automation Steps" (SM205000) definition. You will not find such actions somewhere in the code. If you are asking about "Requests" (RQ301000) screen - you will find "Cancel Request" action there, which includes several steps:

- Set RQRequest.Rejected = true
- Set RQRequest.Status = "L" (Canceled)
- Document.View.RequestRefresh() (not sure you really need this)
- Save.Press()

There are 2 possible ways to invoke the action

- Call `PXAutomation.ApplyAction(graph, graph.Actions["Action"], "Cancel Request", row, out rollback);` where graph - is your `RQRequestEntry` graph instance, row - `RQRequest` object
- Manually call all steps from the code (`RQRequest.Rejected = true, RQRequest.Status = "L", Save.Press()`)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OErz3.png)

Comment: Thanks! Also reviewed this post https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/04/running-automaton-button-from-code.html and worked as expected.